# Transactionscope .net core 2

Tags: transactionscope, .net-core-2.0

I get this error

> Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported

when dedugging the code below in .net core 2 console app on my win 10 PC with VS 2017 15.3.2 (System.Data.SqlClient v4.4.0)

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(_configuration["ConnectionString"]))
  {
    connection1.Open();
  }
  scope.Complete();
}
```

Transactionscope is part of the .net standard 2 and the code above was taken from microsoft's documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-2.0

Answer (score 1):

I think this has already been reported to Microsoft as an issue on GitHub

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24282

Answer (score 1):

Installing `System.Data.SqlClient` >= 4.8.2 should fix this issue.